# Extracting basic PHP echo from IF statement

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, if-statement, echo

The following code is for a Wordpress plugin, it displays points and tank of a user:

```
<?php
if(function_exists('cp_displayPoints') && $authordata->ID){
  echo '<span class="cubepoints_buddypress">'; cp_displayPoints($authordata->ID); echo '</span>';
  if(function_exists('cp_module_ranks_getRank')) echo ' <span class="cupepoints_buddypress_rank">'.cp_module_ranks_getRank($authordata->ID).'</span>';
}
?>
```

I am trying to extract these two echo functions from the If statement but only succeeded with one of them. I can echo the points like this:

```
<?php cp_displayPoints($authordata->ID); ?>
```

Works fine. Now I tried doing the same with the second echo:

```
<?php cp_module_ranks_getRank($authordata->ID); ?>
```

But it did not work. Obviously, there is some basic thing that I am missing here. Do you know what it is?

Comment: Since I know when you call a function it depends what is in the function, if cp_displayPoints($authordata->ID) has echo in somewhere obviously it will print out the screen, perhaps cp_module_ranks_getRank($authordata->ID) has no echo, then review the function to find out where it has or not an echo. Also you can compare the two functions.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do better. Note that I am very new to PHP coding and programming in general. I learned what the term echo means yesterday.

Comment: What I said is the same of the answer but in other words. It means look inside the function if it echoes the value if not, obviously echo it. Great you solve the problem, and welcome to PHP world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one likely prints directly to output, while the second returns its value. So, you need to [`echo()`](http://php.net/echo) the second one, just as they're doing in your sample code:

```
<?php echo cp_module_ranks_getRank($authordata->ID); ?>
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the explanation. I have upvoted this and will accept it as the correct answer once the time limit ends.